# Why ClusterRole admin can't modify resource namespace

Tags: kubernetes, k8s-cluster-role

Clusterrole `cluster-admin` can modify resource `namespace`, while `admin` can't.

Why creating `namespace` needs higher permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when specifying the subject's type to User instead of ServiceAccount that solves your issue

Try using this command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding test-sa-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=test-sa
```

This will create a role to the user after that try to modify  the namespaces accordingly.